# How can I echo the "Username/Email should not be empty!" in the fields?

Tags: php

Ok, right now when the user does not fill in the fields correctly he is redirected to this[image] What I want is to make it more user-friendly and so the user can see their mistake in the fields or at least in the same page without being redirected to this white page.

Here is my code so far:

**Conn.php**

```
<?php


session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password =$_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];



if(!empty ($username) && !empty($email)){
    if(!empty ($password)){



        $host = "host";
        $dbusername = "user";
        $dbpassword = "********";
        $dbname = "dbname";

        $conn = new mysqli ($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);

        if(mysqli_connect_error()){
            die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_errno().')' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }



else{

    $username= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["username"]);
    $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["email"]);
    $phone= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["phone"]);
    $password= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["password"]);
    $password = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);  

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(username,password,email,phone) values('$username','$password','$email','$phone')";
    if($conn->query($sql)){ 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "error: ". $sql."<br>".$conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
}       



        }
    else {
        echo "Password should not be empty";
        //echo "<script>alert('Password should not be empty!');</script>";
        die();
    }
}

else{
    echo "Username/Email should not be empty";
    die();  
}



?>
```

**SignUp.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'header.php';

?>

<h1 class="register"> Rigester </h1>
<div class="help" >

<form  method="POST" action="conn.php">



      <div class="help">
      <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" >
      </div>
       <div class="help">
      <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" >
      </div>
       <div class="help">
      <input placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email" >
      </div>
       <div class="help">
      <input placeholder="Phone" type="text" name="phone" >    
      </div>

      <input  class="helpbtn" type="submit" name="submit" >

</form>   
</div>
<?php
include_once 'footer.php';

?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: I'd recommend that you use Ajax here. You can also with the help of Ajax, prevent the page from reload of empty variables

Comment: As written above, this code is super dangerous and insecure - You can not use it in a real website, because it will be hacked very easily sooner or later

Comment: Create an error bag in `$_SESSION` to contain validation errors like those. When rendering your form, output error close to the field if there is an error for the field in the error bag.

Comment: Before doing anything else, you should refactor your code to take the above mentioned security concerns into account. Debugging and fixing insecure code is a waste of time since you will need to rewrite parts (or most) of it anyway.

Comment: Thank you guys for the feedback. I am still new to PHP but I am aware of the fact that it is insecure. I am still working on making it more secure.

Comment: Ok. I think I managed to improve my security at least a little bit. Now the password is hashed and is not readable in the database. I am not sure how to log in with same credentials now?

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this
in conn.php:

```
// form error
if(condiftion){
    header("location:www.example.com/SignUp.php?msg=1");
}
```

in signup.php

```
//you can print diffrent message By judging value of $_GET[''msg'] with switch
<?php echo isset($_GET["msg"]) "your message" : "";?>
```

Comment: OP doesn't want redirect. Your answer is way off. With your answer, an attacker can easily manipulate the value of `$_GET['msg'];`

Comment: @Akintunde007 it just a flag to judge weather print a message .and it is only an simple example, you can filter illegal characters before use it.so,if he doesn’t want to redirect,he can use Ajax